# issue in consuming existing data after re-build and deploy nodes

Tags: corda

i created one transaction using . After that i made some changes in code and build and deploy the nodes successfully. I tried to consume previously created data to create new data. But it led to Contract constraints failed error. But i didn’t get any error at the time of creating new data and consuming the same to create another transaction at that instance.

Comment: We need more information. What is the error you're getting? Where and when is it being thrown?

Comment: Contract constraints failed for contract name, transaction: 
this is the error am getting.

Comment: this error is thrown by TransactionVerificationException

Comment: Is your code available as a repo somewhere? Can you link to it?

Comment: class ContractRejection(txId: SecureHash, contract: Contract, cause: Throwable)
        : TransactionVerificationException(txId, "Contract verification failed: ${cause.message}, contract: $contract", cause)

Comment: after redeployment, i can able to create new transaction and consume the same

Comment: no @Joel. this is organization PoC

Comment: is there any time session or lock time in contract if we made redeployment?

Comment: am using version 1.0. is this would be version problem? if it is, version 3.1 could rectify this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TransactionVerificationException.ContractConstraintRejection**

This exception is thrown when you have existing states in the vault and you updated the contract code and redeployed.

1. Every time at the node startup CorDapp Jar are scanned and Jar which has Contract classes are uploaded to attachment storage, and the `hash` of the Jar used as `Attachment ID` to attach the `contract` to a `transaction`.
2. Now, consider, you have a first fresh version of CorDapp - `Attachment ID` is: `3B6CA18330500C738455444115C49769D54074CE3CFFB194D8943F34494DB0A4`
3. To create `State` on vault, you build the `transaction`, Corda auto-attach the `contract` using `Attachment ID` given above.
4. Then, consider, you changed the code and re-ployed the CorDapp, now jar hash changed, new `Attachment ID` is: `F054BA8C1A67BAABF58539F8718B8A62DC770157D9F1D01434B86E73AD2A9217`
5. **My finding,** when you create any new the transaction, Corda uses new/recent `Attachment ID` to attach specified `contract`.
6. For example, *You want to update State already present on vault.*

   > a. You created a transaction which has one input and it's output state.
   >
   > b. You sent this transaction for verification.
   >
   > c. There is check verifies that `input state` `contract` `Attachment Id` and current `transaction` `Attachment Id` must be same.
   >
   > d. But right now `input state` pointing to **old** `Attachment ID` and `transaction` pointing **new** `Attachment ID`. Here check fails and throws a `TransactionVerificationException.ContractConstraintRejection` exception.

Comment: Thanks @Balaji More. how to rectify this issue?

Comment: `hash` is calculated on the content of a `Jar` file, any change to it effectively create new `hash`.

Comment: @Joel or anyone from Corda plaform team could help here. You could follow-up further on [Slack](https://cordaledger.slack.com/) referencing this issue.

Comment: could you hepl me for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502498/getting-error-while-redeploying-nodes

Comment: If you don’t want to have this problem for now, when you build your transactions you can set the `AlwaysAcceptAttachmentConstraint`.
like this: `addOutputState(.., .., AlwaysAcceptAttachmentConstraint)`

This is not the very secure way to use it, but till things get stable you can go with this option.

Comment: For more detail on `contract constraint` refer link - https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html

Comment: @rafarossi, If you still want to consume old `State` exist on `Vault`, then you first need to change the `Attachment` `constraint` on the `state` by running the `Upgrade Transaction`: https://docs.corda.net/contract-upgrade.html

Comment: these are all saying like contract upgrade. but here i didn't do any changes in contract.

Comment: You have changed the `Jar` file content, not in contract class but other classes, so `hash` is different. The `State` always refers to contract `Jar` file using it's `hash`.