# Getting error while redeploying nodes

Tags: corda

I am still using Corda 1.0 version. when i try to redeploy nodes with existing data, getting below error while start-up but able to access the nodes . If i clear the data and redeploy the nodes, i didn't face these error message.

```
Logs can be found in                    : 
C:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\kotlin-
source\build\nodes\xxxxxxxx\logs
Database connection url is              : jdbc:h2:tcp://xxxxxxxxx/node
E 18:38:46+0530 [main] core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to 
create netty connection
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty 
all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
Incoming connection address             : xxxxxxxxxxxx
Listening on port                       : 10014
RPC service listening on port           : 10015
Loaded CorDapps                         : corda-finance-1.0.0, kotlin-
source-0.1, corda-core-1.0.0
Node for "xxxxxxxxxxx" started up and registered in 213.08 sec


Welcome to the Corda interactive shell.
Useful commands include 'help' to see what is available, and 'bye' to shut 
down the node.

Wed May 23 18:39:20 IST 2018>>> E 18:39:24+0530 [Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-server-
org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImp
l$3@4a532271)] core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to create 
netty connection
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-
all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
```

Comment: You could get more detail error by setting logging level through command line argument: 
e.g. `runnodes.bat --logging-level=DEBUG`

Comment: This issue is caused by a zombie Java process that is holding one of the ports your node is trying to start on.

Try killing it using `killall java -9` on osX, or `wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Artemis failed to connect to the node which means the node fails to start.

You should look at the log and if there are any other previous Corda node started which occupy the node.

If there are any legacy Corda nodes that have not been killed, try `ps -ef |grep java` to see if there is any other java still alive. Especially look for the port number and check if they are overlapped